# How to make a datetime a bigint?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, error-handling, concatenation

I want to convert a datetime to big int. For Example. I have an entry in the file that i read in php like normal datetime, `"2021/05/20 11:46"`(i keep it in a variable named $data) that i want to transform into a bigint like `202105201146` (year+month+day+hour+minute) . I tried to work around and make it working, but I still get the error :

> "Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given in".  >

The line in question is :

`$ID=  date('Y', $data) . date('m', $data) . date('d', $data). date('G', $data) . date('i', $data). date('s', $data);`

Comment: As a note, you don't need to do separate calls. Just do `date('YmdGis', $data);`

Comment: I think you need convert your data to UNIXTIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

You must first convert it into a datetime object, and then format it as "bigint":

```php
$dateAsString = '2021/05/20 11:46';
$datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i', $dateAsString);
echo $datetime->format('Ymdhi'); // 202105201146
```

*However*, since the error is asking for a timestamp (as int value), it could be better to use the `getTimestamp()` method of `DateTime` class, which returns the epoch timestamp:

```php
$dateAsString = '2021/05/20 11:46';
$datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i', $dateAsString);
$timestamp =  $datetime->getTimestamp(); // 1621511160
```

Comment: The however portion is not required. `2021/05/20 11:46` is conveted to `202105201146` in your first example.

Comment: The error he's getting is talking about a timestamp, hence I only suggested that it could be the proper value to use.